# Using Python I want to set the font as a custom from dafont.com but it's not working

Tags: python-3.x

Tried importing this font but there isn't anything on the internet to explain how to do it.

https://www.dafont.com/oceanic-drift.font

I tried doing it on my own so I don't think you'll find it useful but I'm putting the code anyway:

```
import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager
from fontTools.ttLib import TTFont
font = TTFont('/Windows/Fonts/oceanicdrift.ttf')

font_dirs = ['C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Fonts\\oceanicdrift.ttf', ]
font_files = font_manager.findSystemFonts(fontpaths=font_dirs)
font_manager.fontManager.ttflist.extend(font_files)

figure(figsize=(15, 12))
ax = plt.gca()
plt.text(0.5, 0.5, 'TEST text', color='Black', fontsize=30, fontname=font)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ax = plt.subplot()
fpath = os.path.join(mpl.get_data_path(), r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\oceanicdrift.ttf")

prop = fm.FontProperties(fname=fpath)

plt.text(0.5, 0.5, 'TEST text', color='Black', fontsize=30, fontproperties=prop)
plt.show()
```

After some more research I came to this.

Here is what you need to import for it to work:

```
import os
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```